# Grabbing assigned VM names by entering username in Vmware Horizon (PowerCLI)

Tags: powershell, automation, vmware, vsphere, powercli

I've been working on a PowerShell code to grab VM names from all desktop pools.

I'm using PowerCLI with PowerShell 7 installed.

I have managed to get an output of all the users and their assigned machines. But, I'm having difficulties in optimizing the code in a way that I can input a single user name and it will only show me that user's assigned VM.

Here is the code I've got so far

```
#Import-Module VMware.VimAutomation.Core
#Import-Module Activedirectory

Connect-VIServer -server servername123 -Force
Connect-HVServer -server server.name.123

$uname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the user name you wish to find:' #User-Input

$Global:DefaultHVServers

$query = New-Object "Vmware.Hv.QueryDefinition"
$query.queryEntityType = 'SessionLocalSummaryView'
$qSrv = New-Object "Vmware.Hv.QueryServiceService"


$PCs = ($qSRv.QueryService_Query($global:DefaultHVServers[0].ExtensionData,$query) | 
Select -ExpandProperty Results |
Select -ExpandProperty NamesData |
Select-Object -Property UserName,MachineOrRDSServerName)


$PCs | % {"$($_.UserName.Split("\")[1]) `t`t $($_.MachineOrRDSServerName) "}
```

In the last line of the code, I am formatting the table to remove unnecessary content.

```
$PCs | % {"$($_.UserName.Split("\")[1]) `t`t $($_.MachineOrRDSServerName) "}
```

Can someone help me in grabbing username from console and only displaying the VMs that they are assigned to?

I have tried googling for a solution but couldn't find anything relevant.

Thanks!!

**Note**: I have declared a variable uname but haven't used it yet. I'm unsure how can I use it in this usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around more in the deepest subreddits, I found a post that solved my question.

https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/d547nt/horizon_view_powercli_help/

Below is the code which utilizes **QueryFilterEquals**
from **VMware.Hv.Equals** class to grab usernames and their properties.

I'm skipping the connections portion of the code, it is the same mentioned in the question.

```
#Get User Input for UserName
$UserName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the user name you wish to find:'

#Create Horizon Services object
$HorizonServerServices = $global:DefaultHVServers[0].ExtensionData

#Create Query Definition object with EntityType SessionLocalSummaryView
$HorizonQuery = New-Object VMware.Hv.QueryDefinition
$HorizonQuery.QueryEntityType = 'SessionLocalSummaryView'

#Create Query Filter Object
$QueryFilterEquals = New-Object VMware.Hv.QueryFilterEquals
$QueryFilterEquals.MemberName = 'namesData.userName'
$QueryFilterEquals.value = "domain.loc\$UserName"


$HorizonQuery.Filter = $QueryFilterEquals

$HorizonQueryService = New-Object VMware.Hv.QueryServiceService
$SearchResult = $HorizonQueryService.QueryService_Query($HorizonServerServices, $HorizonQuery)

if ($SearchResult.Results)
{
    $SearchResult.Results.Namesdata
}
```

We do not have to delete the query at the end as it doesn't consume any server-side resources. It is a virtual query. Refer to the link given below for detailed info on how QueryService works.

Refer to: https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/e2e25628-4ed2-43fc-8bad-54fb86f3bb0f/8e4d2491-c740-4778-ac43-ba8fc0ec8175/doc/queries-landing.html